# Proof of the inclusion sets

Tags: probability

I would know why if I have $A \subseteq B ,\:$ I obtain $P(B)\geq P(A)$

Thanks to everyone

Comment: What do you mean with $P(B)\color{red}\ge P(A)$?

Comment: What do you mean with $\color{red}{P(A)}$?

Comment: Did you mean $P(A)\subseteq P(B)$?

Comment: @Bernard I have to proof that if $A$ is included in $B$ the probability that an event in $B$ ($P(B)$) is greather or equal of an event in $A$ ($P(A)$)

Comment: Again... look at how probability is **defined**.  One of the *axioms* (*or if not an axiom itself in your definition, follows immediately from axioms*) needed for a measure to be a measure in the first place (*and in particular a probability measure*) is precisely that... that $A\subseteq B$ will imply $\mu(A)\leq \mu(B)$ where $\mu$ is a measure, or even more specifically that $Pr(A)\leq Pr(B)$ where $Pr$ is a probability measure.

Comment: See [probability axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms).  The property you mention is in the article not listed as an axiom itself, but is the first in it's list of consequences.

Comment: @StubbornAtom what is $P(B \setminus  A)$ I never seen before... Is like $A-B$?

Comment: @BigBro: It is the ‘official’ notation.

Comment: @Bernard thanks for the explanation

Comment: @StubbornAtom Unfortunately no but I have add to my bookmark because is useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Write $B= A\cup (B\smallsetminus A)$ and use the axioms of a probability measure.

Comment: Exactly, I have tried this way... $B=A \cup (B-A)$ so I have rewrite all like: $P(B)=P(B-A)+P(A)$ and after this I have directly the solution $P(B) \geq P(A)$ and I would understand the step between $P(B)=P(B-A)+P(A)$ and $P(B) \geq P(A)$

Comment: By definition, $P(B\smallsetminus A)\ge 0$.

Comment: so after this I haven't other conditions to take in consideration?

Comment: No. It only uses two basic axioms of probability.

Comment: Ok thanks for your explanation... I proved this mechanically but something isn't clear... but now everything is ok!  Can you give me the two axioms used? (Only the name is ok)

Comment: The first is that a probability measure  takes its values in $[0,1]$. The second is that it is additive w.r.t. pairwise disjoint sets.

Comment: w.r.t.?? I'm not mother tongue UK/USA so I don't understand some words... sorry

Comment: It's simply the acronym of *with respect to* (it's not my mother tongue either).

Comment: perfect... thank you so much for your availability!